# How can I update a div that is clicked on in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to click on a specific tile (div) from the many tiles created by the loop, and have the background color of it change along with increment the value within that specific div.

See the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>    
</body>

<script>
var id = 0; // variable for generating unique id
var x = 0;

function cdiv(ele) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = 'div' + id;
  div.id = 'div' + id++; // get unique id and increment id value
  div.style.width = "10px";
  div.style.height = "10px";
  div.style.background = "red";
  div.innerHTML = x;

 ele.appendChild(div);
}

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "1000px"; ///10 times of inner divs
div.style["overflow-x"]= "visible"; // to show overflow
document.body.appendChild(div);
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (b = 0; b < 10; b++) { 
    cdiv(div);
  }
}

function clr(a) {
  a.style.background = "yellow";
  a.innerHTML += 1
}   

</script>

</html>
```

Here, I have set up a function 'clr()' to change the color, but I do not know how to go into the div's tag and add a function attribute. I would be able to do other things such as mouseover once I figure that.

Secondly, the value of x needs to be incremented as the tile is clicked. That is also part of the 'clr()' function I have set up.

Comment: The code is currently setting the div's innerHTML twice: (1) `div.innerHTML = 'div' + id;`and (2) `div.innerHTML = x;`. Do you want to increment the global variable `x` or that specific element's value? Or do you want to create a new div next to the clicked div, with an incremented value?

Comment: The first part you've pointed out is part of assigning a unique ID for each div. The second part is a function that would increment the value within the div. I probably have it wrong, but by 'a' in the function 'clr()' I hope to pass through a div and change it's background color as well as the value it currently holds (which is 0 for now - the default value it got from x)

Comment: In the `clr` function, `a.innerHTML += 1` will append the string `'1'` to `a.innerHTML`. You probably want to use `a.innerHTML = parseInt(a.innerHTML) + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the div's id using a click event handler.

```
  div.addEventListener("click", clr);
```

Once that div is clicked, the clr function is fired with an event.
Using that event, you can get the clicked element's id using the `currentTarget` property:

```
  var clickedElement = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id);
```

Then, once you get that element id, you can also access the div's properties such as innerHTML by:

```
var currentXValue = clickedElement.innerHTML;
```

And then you are able to increment by doing so.

```
var id = 0; // variable for generating unique id
var x = 0;

function cdiv(ele) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = 'div' + id;
  div.id = 'div' + id++; // get unique id and increment id value
  div.style.width = "10px";
  div.style.height = "10px";
  div.style.background = "red";
  div.innerHTML = x;
  div.addEventListener("click", clr); // this is the click event
  ele.appendChild(div);
}

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "1000px"; ///10 times of inner divs
div.style["overflow-x"] = "visible"; // to show overflow
document.body.appendChild(div);
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
    cdiv(div);
  }
}

function clr(e) {
  var clickedElement = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id); // gets the clicked element's id 
  var currentXValue = clickedElement.innerHTML; // gets the clicked element's current value
  clickedElement.style.background = "yellow";
  currentXValue++ // increments clicked element's current value
  clickedElement.innerHTML = currentXValue; // sets clicked element's new value
}
```

Here's the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/94atctxf/

I hope I understood it correctly.

Comment: You got it! very much appreciated. I'd gotten to adding an event listener, but I didn't know where to find how to use it properly for my purpose. what you did to the function was magic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple JavaScript. Every Click, The Background Is Changed and 1 is added to k.

HTML:

```
<div onClick="test(this)">Click Me</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var k = 0;

function test(a){
  k++; //adding 1 to k
  a.style.color = "white"; //Font Color
  a.style.backgroundColor = "black"; //Background Color
  a.innerHTML = "Click Me " + k; // dsiplaying k
}
```

See an [Example](http://codepen.io/romankoval10/pen/qNbEXO).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have specific divs written out myself in html. The script creates the divs so I need to somehow add the onclick function in the div being created